# Array programming in java large size

Tags: java

How to declare an array of size 10^9 in java ?.I have tried  Array list but the problem is i need to find minimum and maximum element in array and so I need to compare 0th element of an array with all other elements of array and i initially need some fixed size of array which is required in the input format of array on code-chef. Can anybody help?. I tried using long array but it gave out of memory error.

Comment: can you add more code snippet of what you are tying to do?

Comment: Just `new Whatever[1000000000]` to create the array. But if that's an array of references, and if we assume 4 bytes per reference, then that's ~4 GB of data. If you're running out of memory, try working with -Xmx parameters. (That said, if you only want to fetch out the min and max values of N elements, you can do that in constant space -- no need to load up the whole array.)

Comment: If you don't have that much memory, perhaps you could use a file to supplement the operation.

Comment: If it's on code chef, there almost certainly is a way to do what is being asked *without* storing all that data in memory. You should explain what problem you are really trying to solve - at the moment it sounds like [an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179508).

Comment: here Ai stands for array elements.These are the constraints:    Constraints. I am concerned with Ai 

1 ≤ N, Q ≤ 10^5
0 ≤ t ≤ 10^9

1 ≤ Ai ≤ 2

1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^9

Comment: long a[] = new long[1000000000]; this is what i am trying to do and the codechef compiler gives this error:-exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Comment: Your constraints specify that each individual element must be <= 10^9, not that you need to allow for 10^9 elements. What is `N`? What is `Q`? What is `t`?

Comment: @vidhit You won't be able to create such a large array on code chef. What is the actual problem (what you describe with your constraints is hard to understand)?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom the codechef compiler tests for the maximum value if the maximum value case is satisfied then only you can get the correct answer

Comment: @assylias here is the link https://www.codechef.com/JUNE16/problems/DEVARRAY but let me tell you my code is giving the exact required output on codechef compiler but still when i submit the code it gives wrong answer i assume it is because when i take the size of array as 10^9 it is showing out of memory and 10^9 can be the size of array according to one of the constraints

Comment: @vidhit I have not read in detail but it appears that the size of the array is N and N is 10^5 max (i.e. 100,000, which should easily fit in memory). And the input contains the value of N, so you only need to build an `int[N]` with N being whatever is on the first line of the input.

Comment: Well, there you go. You don't need to create an array with 10^9 elements. You just need to create one with `N` elements, and `N <= 10^5`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Actually I got interested and couldn't resist writing a solution: you don't need to store the numbers at all - no array involved...

Comment: @assylias really no array involved??

Comment: @vidhit hint: the target is "valid" if you have `min(numbers) <= target <= max(numbers)` - so you only need the min and max, therefore no array needed.

Answer (score 2):

A Java array can have a maximum size equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (or in some cases a slightly different value) which is about 2.3 * 10^9, so creating that large an array is theoretically possible. However since 10^9 would mean the prefix giga (to make it easier to read) the array would have a size of at least 1GB (when using `byte[]`). Depending on the data type you're using the array probably just takes too much memory (an `int[]` would already take up 4GB).

You could try to increase the JVM's max memory by using the `-Xmx` option (e.g. to allow a maximum of 4GB you could use `-Xmx=4g`) but you're still limited by the maximum of adressable memory (e.g. IIRC a 32-bit JVM can only adress up top 4GB in total) and available memory.

Alternatively you could try and split the array over multiple machines or JVMs and employ some distributed approach. Or you could write the array to a (memory mapped) file and keep only a part of the array in memory.

The best approach, however, would probably be to check whether you *really* need that much memory. In many cases using some clever algorithms or structures can dramatically reduce memory requirements. What to use depends on what you're trying to achieve in the end though.